# Condition Formatting - how to have formula with two conditions based on which there will be formatting?

Tags: conditional-formatting

I almost never work with Excel, this is a one time thing probably.

I have the following table:

[image]

I want the Due Date to format when: Duedate has passed the date of today and Status is not equal to 'Closed'. I am using the conditional formatting function 'new rule' --> "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

What I have now: ="$I$3<TODAY()AND+$J$3!="Closed" but this doesn't work.

Then I tried: =AND(ISNUMBER(FIND($J3,"In Progress|On-Track|Overdue|Open|")),$I3<=TODAY())

and then I get the prompt:

[image]

How must I change my formula to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> =AND(I3<TODAY();J3<>"Closed";I3<>"")

Also don't use dollar signs here to lock the row and column, since then all rows will get the color of the first row

[image]

Comment: Hi Bert- this makes all my white non value cells red. And leave the cells that are actually past due date without format.

Comment: the empty cells are easy to fix. you can make a check making sure the cell is not empty -->
=AND(I3<TODAY();J3<>"Closed";I3<>"")

For me the formula works. Are you sure you have setup the date format correctly, so the comparison with today goes fine? you might want to compare the cell with today in a normal formula and see result of that.

Comment: Great! no problems. Then just checkmark it is the right solution for future users.

Comment: Will do! Bert, what if I want to alter the formula to also include changing the value of column J to "overdue" if I3 is in fact <TODAY(). What must I include in the formula ?

Comment: Bit hard to say, since we don;t know what the current logic is in cell J3. but you can do something as =if(and(I3<today();[current logic J3]<>"Closed");"Overdue";[current logic J3])